# Can I enter Romania visa-free if I hold an unused multiple-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, romania, thai-citizens

I have a plan to attend academic conference in Romania and then take a short stay in Austria. Unfortunately, the Embassy of Romania in Thailand is temporarily closed and I have to go to Philippines for visa issuing instead. They also give me a link as the following

"Holders of Schengen valid visas with multiple entries may enter Romania and stay until the date of the validity of the Schengen visa. Further information available at: http://bangkok.mae.ro/en/node/871"

If I apply for multiple entry Schengen visa for Austria, but I will enter Romania first and go for Austria later. Would it be possible in this case? I have written email to ask Ministry of Foreign Affairs in Romania, but did not get any response for a while.

Comment: **If** you get such a visa, you should be able to enter Romania but getting a multiple-entry visa from Austria with a short touristic trip as the premise seems difficult. They are not supposed (and unlikely) to issue one to help you go to Romania, but only if you have a genuine reason to make repeated trips to Austria and an history of using Schengen visas correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now my wife got an Austria Schengen VISA for one month (but only a duration of stay for 6 days). I really did not understand that We have a right to stay in Romania for 6 days or the right of stay in Romania+Austria is for 6 days. If being the latter case, it should be a big problem for us now.

Comment: You have the right to stay in Austria (and the Schengen area) for six days, independent of any stay in Romania. I think you may also have the right to stay in Romania for six days (so 12 days in total) *before* using your visa in Austria. But do note that *it's only the case if you have a **multiple entry** visa* (which seems unlikely for a 6-day visa). **Did you check that?** (There is a "number of entries" field on the visa sticker.)

Comment: Thank you. Yes number of entries is MULTI  TYPE C, duration of stay 6 days. I am so confused right now because We will enter Romania first. The embassy of my country in Thailand informed me in email that we have the right to stay in both Romania and Austria for 6 days only.

Comment: That's definitely not true. I am not 100% sure about the rules and practices in Romania but a prior stay there definitely does not change anything to your right to stay in the Schengen area. Might it be that your country's embassy was confused about Romania's current status?

Comment: Thank you very much. I will arrive Romania tomorrow and let's see how many day we can stay in Romania.

Answer (score 0):

We stayed in Romania for 6 days as stated in Schengen because we entered Romania first. However, if a duration of Schengen stay is 6 days and you enter schengen country first for 4 days, a number  of day staying in Romania will be left for 2 days only.

Comment: Thanks for sharing with us. It would have been better to sign in to the same account though.